# Problem with a Moving & Rotating Map?

Tags: c#, .net, image

I have a image of a Map and a smaller PictureBox control.

I'm getting input from my joysyick. My the Y takes the image up and left
Adn the X actually rotates the image..

My problem is when i rotate the Image, the Y axis rotates with it, so when i move up again it wont really go up.. it will go the the new direction the Y axis points too..

Here is my code if you could understand my problam..

```
    public void UpdateTurret()
    {
        while (js != null)
        {
            js.GetData();
            Thread.Sleep(80);
            MapY += js.State.Y;
            MapRotation += js.State.X;
            {
                Image map = Properties.Resources.Map;
                Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)map.Clone();
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmp);
                g.TranslateTransform((float)bmp.Width / 2, (float)bmp.Height / 2 - (MapY / 2));
                g.RotateTransform(MapRotation);
                g.TranslateTransform(-(float)bmp.Width / 2, -(float)bmp.Height / 2 + (MapY / 2));
                g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);

                Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmp);
                gfx.DrawPie(new Pen(Color.Blue, 5), bmp.Width/2 - 5, bmp.Height/2 - 5, 5, 5, 0, 360);
                gfx.DrawImage(bmp, 0, MapY);

                picBoxMap.Image = (Image)bmp;

                float rot = MapRotation;
                rot = (float)Math.Abs((rot - 360*Math.Ceiling(rot / 360)));
                DrawString = (rot).ToString() + "° Y:" + MapY.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem now is that the rotation point is always centered, i want my rotation point to be the new position i reached.

So i figured out it should be like this:

```
g.TranslateTransform((float)bmp.Width / 2, (float)bmp.Height / 2 - MapY);
g.RotateTransform(MapRotation);
g.TranslateTransform(-(float)bmp.Width / 2, -(float)bmp.Height / 2 + MapY);
```

But this cause another bug. Now when i rotate the Image, the Y axis rotates with it, so when i move up again it wont really go up.. it will go the the new direction the Y axis points too..

Anyone has an idea on solving this issue?

---

**EDIT**:

Here is my new code:

```
    public void UpdateTurret()
    {
        while (js != null)
        {
            js.GetData();
            Thread.Sleep(80);
            MapY += js.State.Y;
            MapRotation += js.State.X;
            {
                Image map = Properties.Resources.Map;
                Size mapSize = map.Size;
                Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)map.Clone();
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmp);

                Matrix transformMatrix = new Matrix();

                transformMatrix.Translate(-mapSize.Width / 2, -mapSize.Height / 2, MatrixOrder.Append);
                transformMatrix.Rotate(MapRotation, MatrixOrder.Append);
                transformMatrix.Translate(mapSize.Width / 2, mapSize.Height / 2, MatrixOrder.Append);

                transformMatrix.Translate(0, MapY, MatrixOrder.Append);

                g.Transform = transformMatrix;
                g.DrawImage(bmp, 0,0);

                picBoxMap.Image = (Image)bmp;

                float rot = MapRotation;
                rot = (float)Math.Abs((rot - 360*Math.Ceiling(rot / 360)));
                DrawString = (rot).ToString() + "° Y:" + MapY.ToString();
            }
        }
        //Draw Cross
        Graphics gfx = picBoxMap.CreateGraphics();
        Rectangle rc = picBoxMap.ClientRectangle;

        gfx.DrawLine(Pens.Red, rc.Width / 2, rc.Height / 2 + 10, rc.Width / 2, rc.Height / 2 - 10);
        gfx.DrawLine(Pens.Red, rc.Width / 2 + 10, rc.Height / 2, rc.Width / 2 - 10, rc.Height / 2);
    }
```

My problem now is that after i move the map on the Y axis, the rotation point stays on the center point.

[image]

And look after i only rotated the map:

[image]

You can see i didn't move the Y axis but it did changed.. because the Rotation point is at the center of the image and not where to red cross is.

I need the rotation point to be at the same position of the red cross.

Comment: Take a look at the the `Graphics.Transform` and `Matrix.Rotate` / `Matrix.Translate` methods. It'll be much simpler than doing what you're doing (drawing an image after each transform).

Comment: @George Hey, can you show me an example? i never used Tranfrom / Matrix before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly a better approach is to use the [`Matrix.Rotate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0s56wcf.aspx) and [`Matrix.Translate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x09w60w4.aspx) methods to get a matrix to set the [`Graphics.Transform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.transform.aspx) to.

Then you can simply draw your map at the origin (ignoring moving and rotating it), and the graphics object will do the rest.

See the examples in the Matrix method links for more info. In their example they draw a rectangle, but you could easily draw your image instead.

---

In my unedited answer i was wrong. I've corrected my code below.

The key things to note are:

1. You want the point the map rotates at to vary according to where the player is, so you should translate the map first (since this will then effect where the rotation happens).
2. I've changed the code to use the `RotateAt` so it's easier to understand. This way we don't need to worry about the extra translations to get the rotation point at the origin then back again.
3. As you want the arrow keys to mean up with respect to the rotated image we can't do it as simply as normal. I've added `Cos` and `Sin` terms in, deduced using basic trigonometry.
4. I've now got 2 pictureboxes, the first shows only the translation, and the direction of the player, the second is a radar like view (which is what you're after). So, this answer has the 2 main map display types, fixed north in picturebox1, rotating north in picturebox2.

Arrow keys move the image, <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd> rotate it.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private PictureBox pictureBox2;

        private Image imageToDraw = null;

        private float imageRotation = 0.0f;
        private PointF imageTranslation = new PointF();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pictureBox1 = new PictureBox() { Top = 20, Left = 10, Width = 280, Height = 310, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle };
            pictureBox2 = new PictureBox() { Top = 20, Left = pictureBox1.Right + 10, Width = 280, Height = 310, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle };

            pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox1_Paint);
            pictureBox2.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox2_Paint);

            this.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(pictureBox2);

            this.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Left = translation only, Right = translation and rotation", Width = Width / 2 });

            this.ClientSize = new Size(pictureBox2.Right + 10, pictureBox2.Bottom + 10);
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                imageToDraw = Image.FromFile("C:\\Map.jpg");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ensure C:\\Map.jpg exists!");
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (imageToDraw != null)
                imageToDraw.Dispose();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            const float MoveSpeed = 5.0f;

            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Q:
                    imageRotation -= 1.0f;
                    break;
                case Keys.E:
                    imageRotation += 1.0f;
                    break;
                case Keys.Up:
                    imageTranslation = new PointF(imageTranslation.X - (float)Math.Sin(imageRotation / 180 * Math.PI) * MoveSpeed, imageTranslation.Y - (float)Math.Cos(imageRotation / 180 * Math.PI) * MoveSpeed);
                    break;
                case Keys.Down:
                    imageTranslation = new PointF(imageTranslation.X + (float)Math.Sin(imageRotation / 180 * Math.PI) * MoveSpeed, imageTranslation.Y + (float)Math.Cos(imageRotation / 180 * Math.PI) * MoveSpeed);
                    break;
                case Keys.Left:
                    imageTranslation = new PointF(imageTranslation.X - (float)Math.Cos(imageRotation / 180 * Math.PI) * MoveSpeed, imageTranslation.Y + (float)Math.Sin(imageRotation / 180 * Math.PI) * MoveSpeed);
                    break;
                case Keys.Right:
                    imageTranslation = new PointF(imageTranslation.X + (float)Math.Cos(imageRotation / 180 * Math.PI) * MoveSpeed, imageTranslation.Y - (float)Math.Sin(imageRotation / 180 * Math.PI) * MoveSpeed);
                    break;
            }

            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            pictureBox2.Invalidate();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (imageToDraw != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.ResetTransform();

                Matrix transformMatrix = new Matrix();

                transformMatrix.Translate(-imageTranslation.X, -imageTranslation.Y);

                e.Graphics.Transform = transformMatrix;

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageToDraw, Point.Empty);

                transformMatrix = new Matrix();

                transformMatrix.Translate(50, 50);
                transformMatrix.RotateAt(-imageRotation, new PointF(20, 20));

                e.Graphics.Transform = transformMatrix;

                e.Graphics.DrawString("^", new Font(DefaultFont.FontFamily, 40), Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (imageToDraw != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.ResetTransform();

                Matrix transformMatrix = new Matrix();

                transformMatrix.Translate(-imageTranslation.X, -imageTranslation.Y);
                transformMatrix.RotateAt(imageRotation, new PointF(pictureBox1.Width / 2 + imageTranslation.X, pictureBox1.Height / 2 + imageTranslation.Y));

                e.Graphics.Transform = transformMatrix;

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageToDraw, Point.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrrrr... i'm really having hard time with this! lol
I hate Matrix Translation and all of this..
Can you show me a piece of code.. i'm sure it wont be more then 5 lines..

Comment: Hey thx, thats exactly what i did.. but the problam is that it's rotating on the Top Left Corner and not from the center.. so it masses all up lol.. i thought i did something wrong.
How can i make it rotate from the center?

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't edit your question so much it changes it, just add edits to the bottom. I don't understand your problem, or what you want. Maybe pictures describing what you want will help?

Comment: I've added a complete sample of what i think you want to achieve to the bottom of my post.

Comment: Hey your code works great.
But still i have a problem i'll add pictures so you can understand.

Comment: Ok, i understand now. Instead of translating by half the image width/height before and after the rotation, translate by the coordinates of the red cross (i.e. half the map window/radar size).

Comment: I added my cross drawing to the code.
The problem is that the red cross is always at the center of the map window. and has diffrent coordinates of the map..
I didn't understand the calculation i need to make..

Comment: Translate it by **rc**.Width / 2 instead of image.width / 2. The key is what i said in my answer: "The way you can get around this is to first translate the image so the point you want to rotate around is on that origin". You know that without any translation the image rotates around the top left. So, to get it to rotate around where the red cross is, you need to move the image so that the red cross would be on the top left. Then you do the rotation. Of course you've also got to move it back. In my program, try removing all matrix lines, adding them in one by one.

Comment: translating it by rc.Width/2 wont do the trick..
try downloading my image http://www.mediafire.com/?su6ec3ctc3upq15
and copy my code so you can see whats the problem..
notice that the Map Widnow has diffrent coordinate count then the coordinate count of the image.
I hope you understand what i'm tryng to say.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3022/discussion-between-danpe-and-george-duckett)

Comment: Hey, Why are you using 2 PictureBoxs ? I'll be happy if you can upload your solution so i can see what you are doing.
I will test it in few hours and let you know thx :)

Comment: I'm using 2 pictureboxes to show what's going on. You can just remove all the code pertaining to picturebox1 if you like. To use the code create a form, then open up the code file and replace it's code with the code in my answer.

Comment: I can describe you in 1 word. **Awesome!**

Comment: Glad i could help. You know if you award the bounty before it runs out i'll get the whole bounty, not just half. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: Hey, I wanted to know if you can put a tweak to make it center the image like it were before.. that i will start from the center and not from Top Left. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean, if you want to start with the player at the center of the image, just change the starting `imageTranslation` to something other than (0, 0)